# How to crop image using GD image functions

Tags: php, image, crop

everything in my code is working great for creating a thumbnail image of an uploaded picture.

now all i need to do is crop the $thumb from the center of the image into a square shape (50x50)

heres my function so far

```
    $ext = end(explode('.', $_FILES['profile_photo']['name']));

    if ($ext == 'jpg' || $ext == 'jpeg' || $ext == 'png' || $ext == 'gif')
    {
        $tmp = $_FILES['profile_photo']['tmp_name'];

        if ($ext=='jpg' || $ext=='jpeg')
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmp);
        else if ($ext=='png')
            $src = imagecreatefrompng($tmp);
        else 
            $src = imagecreatefromgif($tmp);

        list($width,$height) = getimagesize($tmp);

        $thumb_width = 50;
        $thumb_height = ($height/$width) * $thumb_width;
        $thumb_tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);

        $full_width = 200;
        $full_height = ($height/$width) * $full_width;
        $full_tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($full_width, $full_height);

        imagecopyresampled($thumb_tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $width, $height);         
        imagecopyresampled($full_tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $full_width, $full_height, $width, $height);        

        imagejpeg($thumb_tmp, 'images/profile/'.$user['id'].'_'.time().'_thumb.'.$ext, 100);
        imagejpeg($full_tmp, 'images/profile/'.$user['id'].'_'.time().'_full.'.$ext, 100);

        imagedestroy($src);
        imagedestroy($thumb_tmp);
        imagedestroy($full_tmp);

        // delete old image from server if it is not none.png
    }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated! i know that it has something to do with imagecopyresampled but i can't figure out the math for the cropping from the center of the image. i want this to be my own function so please dont recommend me using other peoples classes.

Comment: Do not use the `['type']` data from the _FILES array. it's user provided, and can be forged easily. Also, do not assume that the uploaded images are non-corrupt. You're not checking of the `imagecreatefrom...()` functions actually succeed. As well, your filenames are subject to race conditions - if the thumbnail takes >1 second to create, the full-size image will have a different filename. Maybe it doesn't matter, but it's worth pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after `$full_tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($full_width, $full_height);`, add...

```
if ($thumb_width > $thumb_height) {
    $thumb_offset = array('x' => ($thumb_width/2 - 25), 'y' => 0);
} else {
    $thumb_offset = array('x' => 0, 'y' => ($thumb_height/2 - 25));
}

$square_tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);

imagecopyresampled($square_tmp, $src, 0, 0, $thumb_offset['x'], $thumb_offset['y'], 50, 50, $width, $height);
```

Then save and destroy the temp like the other two images.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the parameters that should be passed to `imagecopyresampled`, as per the PHP manual:

```
imagecopyresampled ( resource $dst_image , resource $src_image , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $dst_w , int $dst_h , int $src_w , int $src_h )
```

From the third parameter on, you basically define how a rectangle on the source image maps to a rectangle on the destination image.

So the first thing you have to do is calculate the rectanle (`x`, `y`, `width` and `height`) which defines the visible area of your original image. These will be the 5th, 6th, 9th and 10th parameters to the function, respectively.

For the destination rectangle, use `0,0` for `x,y`, and `$thumb_width,$thumb_height` for `w,h`, just as you are currently doing.